# Can Python package fsspec read SSH config?

Tags: python, ssh, fsspec

I would like to access remote SSH server files within Python, and found `fsspec`. However, there seems to be few code usage examples.

In particular, I can connect by specifying all SSH config options in the function as:
`fsspec.filesystem('sftp', host='XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', port=XXX, username='XXX', password='XXX')`
However, I would like to connect simply as `fsspec.filesystem('sftp', host='nickname')` as I would do as `sftp nickname` on console, where I have already set all the config options in `.ssh/config`.
This is both for convenience and the fact that I do not want to parse my password in plain text.

I have read the API documentation (https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) and searched a bit but could not find a way yet. May I ask if anyone can point me some direction?

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi! interested in the same topic, and seeing you got no answer, may I ask if you also raised the topic in fsspec Github? if so, maybe there has been some answers there?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your interest! I haven't raise it in GitHub yet coz it was not a must-have feature to my project, so I accessed the files via sshfs to work with my remote files instead. Let me try raise it, now it's not just me with the interest haha

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/intake/filesystem_spec/issues/516
Gonna see how the community reacts to the idea

Comment: awesome, thanks @Claire!